# Shared library is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH but still "getting cannot open shared object file" error

Tags: clang, shared-libraries

I have the following error:

```
armclang: error while loading shared libraries: librui_5.2.0.x64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've found the library it needs:

```
ls /usr/bin/arm/compilers/v6.14/bin
armar  armasm  armclang  armlink  fromelf  libLTO.so  librui_5.2.0.x64.so  libstdc++.so.6  suite_exec
```

So I have that path in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/bin/arm/compilers/v6.14/bin
```

Yet the error persists. Anyone have a clue as to how to check why it's not finding the .so lib?

Comment: Have you exported `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?